# Text file encoded in utf-8, Python giving UnicodeDecodeError, ignore errors not working

Tags: python, utf-8, built-in, python-unicode

I am trying to read-in "CDPQ17CEO.txt" which is encoded in utf-8, see this image:
[Notepad++ Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puAVm.png)

Here is the read_in function (within Letter class):

```
class Letter(object):

def __init__(self, file_path, company_name, author_name=None, author_type = None):
   self.letter = self._read_in(file_path)
   self.company = company_name
   self.author = author_name
   self.type = author_type

def _read_in(self, file_path):
    f = open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').readlines()
    f_stripped = [line.strip() for line in f]
    f.close()
    return ' '.join(f_stripped)
```

Here is the function call:

```
full_file = 'Q:\My Documents\OTPP\letters\CDPQ17CEO.txt'    
letter_dict[name]=px.Letter(full_file, name, author_type=author_type)
```

Here is the error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1936: character maps to undefined>

Why is errors = 'ignore' not doing its job?

If I open and convert the text document to ANSI, re-save and re-run, this does work but I'd prefer to avoid doing this for all the documents I need to read-in.

Thank you!

Comment: Apparently the call to `px.Letter` does not call the method you show here. The "charmap codec" suggests that the `open` function is used without specifying the `encoding` parameter, which entails that a platform-specific default codec is used (which is usually some localized Windows codepage, which are sometimes called "ANSI" within Windows).

Comment: Hmm. I added in the class definition which might make it clearer. I don't see how it could call a different method. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the traceback of the error tell you on which specific line the `UnicodeDecodeError` happens?

Comment: This line:  f = open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore').readlines()

Comment: This means that the `encoding=` parameter is ignored. Is this the built-in `open` function on Python 3?

Comment: Yeah, it's the built-in function.

Comment: Well, if using Python 3's built-in `open` function with `encoding='utf8'` causes a charmap-related UnicodeError, then you have a broken Python. Can you reproduce this behaviour without this Letter class?

Comment: Haha good call. Thanks! I believe the problem is that I created a custom Python package (incorrectly). The package isn't actually importing but it looks like it is because I ran the code and it's hanging out in iPython. It was tracing back to the updated code though which is confusing. I'll post the answer once I figure it out.

Comment: Ok, I see. Btw, if it's you writing this library: don't do `errors='ignore'`. You should let your users know if their input is decoded incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem and solution:

- px module which contained Letter class was not actually importing, although it appeared to be
- resolved problem by adding the path of the module to PYTHONPATH

  ```
  import sys
  sys.path.append('foo')
  ```